# Are there corner connectors for rj45?

Tags: cable

I cant find connectors or cables that have a turn at their end of the connector. (90 degrees)
This might be trivial to some. Do they exist at all?

**Edit:** I draw a picture for this

[image]

Comment: I dunno what you mean.  Can you draw a picture?

Comment: @TomO'Connor I added an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VPI:

- http://www.vpi.us/cat5e-down-angle.html
- http://www.vpi.us/cat6-up-angle.html

BlackBox:

- http://www.blackbox.com/resource/genPDF/SpaceGain-Brochure.pdf
- http://www.blackbox.com/Store/Results.aspx/Cables/CAT6/Patch/90%C2%BA/Shielded/n-4294864837
- http://www.blackbox.com/Store/Results.aspx/Cables/CAT6/Patch/90%C2%BA/Unshielded/n-4294952394
- http://www.blackbox.com/Store/Results.aspx/Cables/CAT5e/Patch/90%C2%BA/Shielded/n-4294858109
- http://www.blackbox.com/Store/Results.aspx/Cables/CAT5e/Patch/90%C2%BA/Unshielded/n-4294858172